# send the enter button input through pipe

Tags: c++, windows

how to send return(enter button) character through program in windows c/c++? I want to send an external program "user name" with enter button through pipe but "\n" and "\r" and EOF are not working.

consider if pPipe is the  pipe stream for sending the data to the remote process stdin...

fprintf(pPipe,"username\n");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence).

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush the data out of the I/O package buffers.

If you're using `<cstdio>` (or `<stdio.h>`) as shown, then:

```
fflush(fp);
```